Unit tests are not passing because of ERC20InsufficientAllowance error
Here is a code
describe("allowances", () => {
        const amount = (20 * multiplier).toString()
        beforeEach(async () => {
          playerToken = await ethers.getContractAt("MegaERC20", deployer)
        })
        it("Should approve other address to spend token", async () => {
          const tokensToSpend = ethers.parseEther("0.01")
          await methERC20.approve(accDeployer, tokensToSpend)
          await playerToken.transferFrom(accDeployer, deployer, tokensToSpend)
          expect(await playerToken.balanceOf(deployer)).to.equal(tokensToSpend)

  it("the allowance being set is accurate", async () => {
          await methERC20.approve(deployer, amount)
          const allowance = await methERC20.allowance(accDeployer, deployer)
          assert.equal(allowance.toString(), amount)

Here is my test output:
  8 passing (2s)
  2 failing

  1) MegaEth Unit Test
       allowances
         Should approve other address to spend token:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'ERC20InsufficientAllowance("0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266", 
0, 10000000000000)'
    at MegaERC20._spendAllowance (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:309)
    at MegaERC20.transferFrom (contracts/HotelToken.sol:46)
    at EdrProviderWrapper.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:428:41)
    at HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\signers.ts:125:18)
    at send (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:313:20)
    at Proxy.transferFrom (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:352:16)
    at Context.<anonymous> (test\hotelToken-unit.test.js:68:11)


  2) MegaEth Unit Test
       allowances
         the allowance being set is accurate:

      AssertionError: expected '0' to equal '20000000000000000000'
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +20000000000000000000

      at Context.<anonymous> (test\hotelToken-unit.test.js:87:18)


Before an address can use transferFrom() to move tokens from another address, they must first be approved to take those tokens.
Since the 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 address wasn't approved prior to calling transferFrom(), you see the ERC20InsufficientAllowance("0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266", 0, 10000000000000) error.
The second error is related to allowance as well, I'm guessing the expected value is the allowance, and the actual value is hard-coded, but I'm not sure since the actual code isn't provided.
For example, if 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 is trying to transferFrom() 100 tokens from 0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8, then 0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8 must first call approve() with the spender address, and the amount of tokens they are allowed to spend: approve(0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, 100e18).
After calling approve(), you should be able to see the allowance updated by calling allowance() like so: allowance(0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8, 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266).
This means we are viewing the amount of 0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8's tokens 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 can spend. Once you have confirmed this value updated correctly, you should be able to call transferFrom() from the 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 address.
EDIT: Based on the code you provided, I'll try to break it down further.
First and foremost, the ERC20 token contract that you are calling approve() on, should be the same token contract that you are calling transferFrom() on.
Secondly, the address (signer with ethers), that calls approve(), shouldn't be the same address calling transferFrom().
In a simplified way:

Alice calls approve(Bob, 100). Bob can now spend 100 of Alice's tokens.
Bob calls transferFrom(Alice, Bob, 100). Bob has now transferred 100 tokens from Alice, to himself.

To revise your code, we can connect two separate signers to the same ERC20 contract that isn't the same as your deployer.
const { assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("allowances", () => {
  let tokenContract;
  let secondAccount;
  const amount = (100e18).toString();
  beforeEach(async () => {
    tokenContract = await ethers.deployContract("Token", ["token", "symbol"]);
    secondAccount = await ethers.getSigner(
      "0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8"
    );
  });
  it("Should approve other address to spend token", async () => {
    const beforeBalance = await tokenContract.balanceOf(secondAccount.address);
    await tokenContract.approve(secondAccount.address, amount);
    await tokenContract
      .connect(secondAccount)
      .transferFrom(
        "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
        secondAccount.address,
        amount
      );
    const afterBalance = await tokenContract.balanceOf(secondAccount.address);
    console.log("beforeBalance:", beforeBalance);
    console.log("afterBalance:", afterBalance);
    assert.equal(beforeBalance + amount, afterBalance);
  });
  it("the allowance being set is accurate", async () => {
    await tokenContract.approve(secondAccount.address, amount);
    const allowance = await tokenContract.allowance(
      "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
      secondAccount.address
    );
    console.log("allowance:", allowance);
    assert.equal(allowance.toString(), amount);
  });
});


Using this ERC20 contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

import {ERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000e18);
    }
}


I just have the code. Your explanations seems confusing. I will appreciate if you can help me with the correction

@EddiePumpin I added a code snippet that I wrote and tested locally, I hope this helps! Let me know if you need any further explanations.


Can you confirm if the two tokens being used are same? methErc20 and playerToken
  await methERC20.approve(accDeployer, tokensToSpend)
  await playerToken.transferFrom(accDeployer, deployer, tokensToSpend)

You are approving in the methERC20 contract, but calling transferFrom in the playerToken contract.

Are you sure accDeployer is the default signer? As ethers js takes the first signer of array to call the contract.


Try this:
await methERC20.connect(accDeployer).approve(deployer, amount)
instead of
await methERC20.approve(deployer, amount)

Yeah, they are the same
But I have debugged it. The issue is from my ERC20 contract

Thanks for the explanation. I understand what you explained but I have debugged it. The issue is from the ERC20 contract
